# Looks like a Special Descriptive riddle today

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Physically I’m burning, but not on fire,
Habitually referenced by the two double five,
Coming from the sky, ground, and water in time,
How about my opposite, he’s simple as that,
Erasing - the walls, Displacing - it falls,
Most often, you’ll find me on the streets, on a score.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> Just plain "Acid?"

Physically I’m burning, but not on fire,

> Acid burns, but is not on fire

Habitually referenced by the two double five,

> (not sure yet)

Coming from the sky, ground, and water in time,

> Acid rain, Soil Acidity, Acid water is water with a potential hydrogen (pH) of less than 7

How about my opposite, he’s simple as that,

> Alkaline is the opposite, it's "Basic" or simple

Erasing - the walls, Displacing - the falls,

> Acid can erase

Most often, you’ll find me on the streets, on a score.

> As the title dictates, **L** **S** **D** can be purchased on the streets, when you "score" some acid for recreational use.

Comment: This sounds right! @Chowzen

Comment: Correct! Well done! Though I was thinking of the two double five as red on the rgb scale, because acid is thought of as red?

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> Acid rain?

Physically I’m burning, but not on fire,

> Acid rain would burn you because it is so acidic, yet is not on fire.

Habitually referenced by the two double five,

> I do not know how this one fits in yet.

Coming from the sky, ground, and water in time,

> Acid rain comes from the sky, can be found on the ground, and in ponds.

How about my opposite, he’s simple as that,

> Regular rain can be found the same way.

Erasing - the walls, Displacing - the falls,

> The pH of acid rain can erode walls and cause problems.

Most often, you’ll find me on the streets, on a score.

> You can find it on the streets.

Comment: You’re very close, when you get the right answer it’ll all make sense

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> LSD (Lysergic acid diethylamide)

Physically I’m burning, but not on fire,

> LSD is AKA acid, which burns

Habitually referenced by the two double five,

> It may be an effect of blurred vision where the user sees doubles. Or the drug causes the user to collapse on all four limbs, which is two sets of hands/feet each with five digits

Coming from the sky, ground, and water in time,

> Made by reacting the colorless Diethylamine liquid (like water) with Lysergic acid (made from natural components)

How about my opposite, he’s simple as that,

> A non-LSD user probably leads a simpler life

Erasing - the walls, Displacing - the falls,

> LSD can erase memories or cause the user to trip and fall.

Most often, you’ll find me on the streets, on a score.

> You can get LSD on the streets, only if you are successful (a score)

Lastly, from the title

> Capital letters spell LSD

Comment: SO close, just not what I’m looking for

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Pollution/litter

Physically I’m burning, but not on fire,

> From the burning of fossil fuels.

Habitually referenced by the two double five,

> I still do not know how this one fits in yet?

Coming from the sky, ground, and water in time,

> Pollution can come from anywhere, from the form of acid rain, plastic, cans, etc.

How about my opposite, he’s simple as that,

> It is simple to keep things clean.

Erasing - the walls, Displacing - the falls,

> Pollution can build up as smog and can make nature look bad.

Most often, you’ll find me on the streets, on a score.

> You can definitely find litter or pollution in the street!

Comment: You were much closer with your first answer